# [UITableViewCellContentView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a custom UITableViewCell with a XIB and connected the labels on it as outlets to the property. When I use that cell in my UITableViewController class to set the text on it, the app crashes during runtime with "[UITableViewCellContentView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" error. Below is my code:

***Custom Table View cell .h and .m files:***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *branchName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *address;
@end

@implementation CustomTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

***My UITableViewController code:***

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *branchListCellId = @"branchList";

    CustomTableViewCell *branchListCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:branchListCellId];

    if (!branchListCell) {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:branchListCellId];
        branchListCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:branchListCellId];
        branchListCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        branchListCell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        branchListCell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        branchListCell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
    }

    return branchListCell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(CustomTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //UILabel *branchName = (UILabel *)[cell.branchName viewWithTag:1];
    cell.branchName.text = [self.branchList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
}
```

Looking at the solution to other questions for the same crash here at SO, I even tries setting viewWithTag to something other than 0. I even tried recreating the outlets. Nothing helped.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Double check that the IBOutlets are properly set up. UITableViewCellContentView is actually a view and not a label. Check that the content view is not connected to any outlet.

Comment: First localize the crash.  Is it on `cell.branchName.text = ...` ??  If so, before that line, let's see the `NSLog(@"%@", cell.branchName);`

Comment: Yes it's on cell.branchName.text line. I did check and the branchName exists. NSLog returns me this - <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x7bf7bba0; frame = (0 0; 702 39.05); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7bf79eb0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bf73680>>

I don't know why it's showing as content view. I had dragged and dropped UILabel on the xib file and then I added outlets for that in my header file.

Comment: Nevermind guys I figured out what the issue was. I had a bad hanging outlet on the entire cell which I may have added accidentally. The outlet was not linked to anything and was only on the xib. Thanks for looking at my question!

Comment: Check cell identifier, it must be same. while dequeuing and nib both are different.